# dataclasses.asdict doesn't work on Python 3.11?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, python-3.11

I tried the following code:

```py
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass


@dataclass
class DC:
    a: int
    b: int

c = DC(a=10, b=5)
dc = asdict(c)
print(dc)
```

On Python 3.10 it works as expected, printing a dictionary as expected. When I try the same with Python 3.11 I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Sources\IAA\python-utils\tests\test_dict.py", line 11, in <module>
    dc = asdict(c)
         ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\311\Lib\dataclasses.py", line 1272, in asdict
    if not _is_dataclass_instance(obj):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name '_is_dataclass_instance' is not defined. Did you mean: 
'config_is_dataclass_instance'?
```

I checked the Python 3.11 documentation, `dataclasses.asdict` is there and should work. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a Python 3.11.1 bug?

The solution for Python 3.11.1 is to add the following lines to my module:

```py
import dataclasses
dataclasses._is_dataclass_instance = dataclasses.config_is_dataclass_instance
```

But it's really not a good solution.

Comment: `is_data_class_instance` is defined in the source for 3.11 and on the main CPython branch on Github.  `config_is_dataclass_instance` is not defined in the source.  Are you using the CPython distribution?

Comment: Well, this is really confusing and may be a result of some extra characters leaking into it, as @user2357112 suggested. Which is weird since I'm using a virtual environment and I've recreated it from scratch. I will reinstall Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've corrupted your `dataclasses.py` somehow, likely with previous edits similar to the one you just made. Trying to restore it manually is far too error-prone. Your best bet at this point is to uninstall and reinstall Python.

Comment: That is unlikely, I'm using a virtual environment, and I've recreated it after seeing this behavior. I'll reinstall Python just to make sure.

Comment: Unlikely as it was, that was the correct solution - reinstalling Python 3.11.1 fixed the issue. Next time I should install Python 3.11 in a directory without write access, so I don't do this by mistake. I wonder why recreating the virtual environment didn't fix this.